# Delay in getting activity data

Tags: google-fit

Help me solving this issue:

Use case: User uses GFit Application to walk and complete 10K steps every day. After completing 10K steps user open our Active Health Application. We refer to Fitness.getHistoryClient() method under “work with historical data” to fetch steps activity data.

Issue: User can see 10K steps in GFit application but the same is not fetched in the Active Health Application when the user opens the application. On application load we try to fetch the latest steps, but we don’t get the same steps which is show in the GFit. But when the user opens the application later sometime the steps are synced. Why is this latency happening? Am I referring to the wrong method. Which method will give me the data as soon as it is visible in GFit.